# Android:how to send a message using bluetooth to multiple devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I send the text file to multiple devices using the following code,

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
String filePath1   =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/filename.txt";
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(newFile(filePath1)).toString()); 
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION,itDevices.getAddress());               values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND); 
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts); 
Uri contentUri = getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I want the same type of code for sending a message. By using the Bluetooth API application when i try to send the message to multiple devices first i connect to a device and send message to that device and again disconnect and connect to another device and send message to another device in this way this goes.

Is it possible to send a message to multiple devices one by one without disconnect the communication ?

Comment: can you please send your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is possible to exchange messages with multiple Android Bluetoooth devices simultaneously - without disconnecting and reconnecting.

Leaving the Android API aside for starters, Bluetooth definitely allows you to connect to and communicate with multiple devices simultaneously.  All Bluetooth connections happen in piconets which include a master and up to 7 slaves.  A device can be part of more then one piconet but this is inefficient (the timing of the two piconets isn't coordinated) and can be unreliable, so if you want to connect to multiple other devices you must make sure you are the master.

I've done this sort of thing with BlueZ (the Bluetooth stack on most Linux and Android devices including [AOSP](http://source.android.com/)) so I can verify that it is fairly straight-forward and works reliably.

However, I've only done one-to-one connections on Android, so I can't say for sure how you control the master-slave assignment there.  Android provides much less power and control compared to regular Linux, and it provides no way to directly read or change the master slave role assignment.

In theory, you should be able to control the roles based on the rule that which-ever side initiates the connection will be the master, but I would want to do some testing to see what else might be going on.  My concern comes mainly from the possibility that one of the client devices (that you expect to be a slave) might already have a connection to e.g. a headset or keyboard, so when it receives the incoming connection request it might request to switch to master role so it can add your server to its piconet.

What I would suggest is, when you are testing, get access to hcitool on one of your devices (e.g. a Linux box or a rooted Android) and do '[hcitool](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hcitool1.html) con' and it will give you a list of the current connections and I think this includes the role.  (hcitool is a standard tool on Linux and is included in AOSP.)  I guess you could also just use the empirical approach: if you are able to create a bunch of simultaneous connections that work reliably then it doesn't matter much how it works - just make sure you test situations where some of the devices have existing connections to other devices.

Sorry about going on, but I think this is a good question and would be interested to hear from people who have done this on Android.  I think I've heard of multi-player Bluetooth games for Android - I wonder if those work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer, It is not possible to send to multiple devices without disconnecting from the current one. Bluetooth API uses One-To-One Connection, which is synchronized itself. So you can not achieve multiple sending using Bluetooth API.

Comment: i want to save some device address and connect to one device and send message after disconnect with it.it again send the same data to other device and so on... is it possible by using bluetoothchat api?

Comment: Yes that's the logic i told you in your previous question. please check my answer there again

Comment: @Lucifer, I don't agree with this accepted answer.  Yes, the Bluetooth sockets API is one-to-one but the underlying Bluetooth connection topology is one-to-seven.  I put my full answer below.  Have I mis-interpreted the question?

Comment: @Lucifer in the case of file transfer i send a file to multiple devices without disconnect .but why it is not happen in sending message to multiple devices??

Comment: Sorry, not much idea about it.